Being taller can/could make him more attractive - Which is appropriate?
Example 1
‎

Being tallercan/could make him more attractive to women. But that's impossibility for him because he's an adult.

It is impossible for him to grow taller at this point so I wonder whether model verb to use, can or could?

Have you ever read, heard anyone say "I like a man/woman with a taller figure"? And it's neither "can" or "could" but it's "would". Being taller would make him more attractive....

Thank you. So you're saying the modal verb has to be hypothetical. So could or would will be more appropriate in my case.

"would" would be my choice. "Could" says it's a possibility but as you said, someone's height is fixed once they enter adulthood. There are very costly, lengthy and painful medical interventions that can add (I think) between one and  three inches to someone's height but these are exceptional and quite rare cases. Overall by using "could" you're saying it's a possibility to be taller but that would be untrue/inaccurate.

Yes this is where it confuses me a little bit. Doesn't "could" also show the unlikelyhood in my original sentence? "Having a tall figure could make him more attractive."

Grab a good grammar book or visit British Council, English Club or even look at Cambridge Grammar and then edit, and explain IN your question why you think "could" could fit :) P.S "having a taller figure", which is not idiomatic, can be said with just one word "taller": You ARE tall, not You HAVE tall.

Can won't work because it's a hypothetical, and the second sentence says it's impossible.
Could is a perfectly fine choice, at least in American English (note the correction to the second part of your sentence):

Being taller could make him more attractive to women. But that's impossible because he's an adult.

Another option is might:

Being taller might make him more attractive to women. But that's impossible because he's an adult.

I disagree with the comments that would is the best choice for the sentences you provided. For example:

Being taller would make him more attractive to women. But that's impossible because he's an adult.

In that example, would implies certainty: that if he were taller, he would be more attractive. That's very different than could, which does not suggest that he would be more attractive; only that he might be.

If he were taller he would be more attractive… "would" is also for imaginary situations.

You have changed the meaning of the sentence because you're stating it as a truth. That's not what "could" means.  Could only means that he might be more attractive, not that he will be.

Yes, it's a slightly different meaning than the given sentence. But it's reasonably likely to be the intended one, and should be approached as such.

Are you saying that you want to ignore the subtle differences between English words and pretend they mean the same thing?
